# Making l-value from r-value

Tags: c++

I've got quite a nifty get fnc which returns pointer to 'a type'. Now I would like to reuse this fnc in fnc set to set some value to this type returned by get:

```
template<class Tag,class Type>
set(Type t, some_value)
{
get<Tag>(t) = value;
}
```

The only problem I have is that: Because get returns pointer and not reference to a pointer the return type is a rvalue which for most cases is fine but not for this. Is there a way to somehow change the returned value into lvalue?

Comment: Am I missing something or couldn't you just do `*get<Tag>(t) = value;`. If that doesn't work, it would help if you would add the definition of `get` to the question.

Comment: @Sven you should post it as a comment so I could accept it. Instead +1 and thanks!

Comment: you're welcome. :) I added it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dereferencing a pointer (with the `*` operator) yields a reference. The type of the reference depends on the type of the pointer. `const T *` becomes `const T &`, while `T *` becomes `T &`.

So, if `get` returns a pointer to a non-`const` variable, you can write:

```
*get<Tag>(t) = value;
```

If `get` does not meet such requirement, and you can't change it, you'll have to give a `set` method instead.

Answer (score 5):

You can simply use this:

```
*get<Tag>(t) = value;
```

The result of dereferencing a pointer is an l-value.